# Hiding URL when redirecting

Tags: url, redirect, cpanel

Is it possible that I can hide the URL where I redirect in CPANEL.

For example :

My Website : www.abc.com

My other website : www.xyz.com

When redirecting from abc.com to xyz.com I want that the adresse stay abc.com !

How can I make it in CPANEL. ??

Comment: not sure from cpanel but it can be done with htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do without using IFRAME is that, you will need to update your vhost config file for this for apache:

Following blog post should give you better idea about that:

http://blogs.digitss.com/apache/mod_proxy-mod_vhost_alias-to-host-multiple-domains-on-web-server-and-running-apache-iis-together/

Scroll down to title: How to host multiple domains/sub-domains on a web-server using Apache Virtual-Hosting (mod_vhost_alias)?

But I doubt how would you get to apache config if you are using shared hosting services? 
Though I am not sure if you have your own server you can do it easily else talk to hosting support.